# Optimal datatype for storing encrypted field data

Tags: c#, sql, encryption, query-optimization

I have a sql databse which is required to store a set of demographic personal data which must be queried quickly.

Requirements dictate the data must be encrypted as it is personal information but also must be searched on to allow record matching.

My question is what datatypes should I define these fields as which will store encrypted data should they be a varchar or varbinary?

My thinking is a that varbinary will reduce the unnecessary overhead in the code to convert the encrypted data to a base64 string, however will querying this data in sql be a lot slower than querying varchar fields.  I am not sure how varbinary fields perform with non clustered indexes?

[edit]
My question is really aimed at query performance.  Will storing varbinary data affect query performance when comparing fields for equality?

Comment: I understand.  That is not an issue as exact comparisons are all that is required.  Query performance is my main concern.  I need to be able to match records on these fields as fast as possible.

Comment: A number of RDBMS allow individual columns to be encrypted *by the database* - absolving you of manually encrypting the data.  Check you documentation to see if your system supports this, and how to query the data stored this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have done in the past is compute a hash of the data that is encrypted and store that in another column.  The hash can be a varchar field which you could index.  Overall I think the varchar field would allow for better query performance compared to a varbinary search.

Comment: I am actually doing this as well on a set of mandatory parameters,  unfortunately I need to add some other parameters for further optional filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You need to secure that database as a whole - not individual fields.  Otherwise you won't be able to query them.

Comment: That's not strictly true.  Query's on exact field comparisons are possible which is what I require. Securing the whole Db has other issues. I am of the opinion data should be encrypted before being passed to the db.  DB encyption as a whole really only secures it if the file is somehow obtained, but other attacks will mean data is compromised

Comment: However other technologies exist to secure data on the wire such as you seem to be describing, such as HTTPS.

Comment: What happens when a SQL login is obtained by whatever means?  The attacker would have plain-text records available.  I take your point about HTTPS but its the data I am worried about, passing it over the wire is dealt with.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but you need to draw the line somewhere.  What happens if you encrypt all fields but the attacker then gets the key - do you encrypt the key?  What you're stating has massive downsides, data such as passwords however can afford to be hashed (as the original data is lost).  This is not what you're asking for.